# Is there a way to do fit_priors=False with pyspark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

In the scikit version of Multinomial Naive bayes there is a parameter for fit_prior.

I have found that for unbalanced datasets usually setting this to false is desired.

For my particular use case setting it raised my AUC from 0.52 to 0.61.

However in the pyspark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes there is no such setting which I think means it is fitting priors regardless.

I "think" I can counteract this with the thresholds param to essentially give more weight to the minority class.

In my case the breakdown is 87% negative and 13% positive.
If I can indeed use the thresholds to in effect do fit_prior to false what value should I use.

Would it be 13/18 ~ 0.15 or ....?
i.e I would create it with NaiveBayes(thresholds=[1,.15])

Or am I completely off base with this?

Comment: Why no just Bootstrap the data?

Comment: well that will be one of the things I will try to improve performance eventually.  Will try various methods of sampling to help fight the imbalance.  This is more to get a baseline of what I was able to accomplish with sci-kit before moving on